# Comparing python input against mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

Hi ive been trying to get my simple python script to compare an input value against multiple values in my mysql database but it wont recognize the correct code when it gets entered. I've seen a couple of the same questions about this but I cannot seem to replicate the results.

What I want to achieve is that when a package trackingcode like "3SDMVN016444927" gets entered it compares it to multiple trackingcodes existing in the database and than enables a relay to open a lock if the trackingcode can be found.

```
import time
import os
from time import time, sleep
import mysql.connector
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
relay = 18;
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay , 0)

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="user",
    passwd="pass",
    database="Package Scanner"
)

mycursor = db.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT TrackingNumber FROM Packages")

code = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in code:
    print(x)

print ("Ready To Take Input")
val = input()
if val == code:
    print ("Code Correct")
    GPIO.output( relay , 1)
    sleep(4 -time() % 1)
    GPIO.output(relay, 0)
    os.system("python3 /home/pi/Solenoidlock/lock2.py")
elif val == exit:
    exit()
else:
    print ("Code Incorrect")
    os.system("python3 /home/pi/Solenoidlock/lock2.py")
```

The output I get when I print "code" is

('3SDMVN016444927',)
('1ZE191X36870159832',)
('JJD000090254011002221222',)

but if I enter one of the codes it does not recognize the code as correct

Comment: do `print(code)` and `print(val)` you're going to find they're very different. You're looking to compare individual elements, which is probably best done when querying the database, not when looping over all the elements later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query the database with the input data, then check if you have a result:

```
import time
import os
from time import time, sleep
import mysql.connector
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
relay = 18
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay , 0)

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="user",
    passwd="pass",
    database="Package Scanner"
)

mycursor = db.cursor(prepared=True)
print ("Ready To Take Input")
val = input()
if val =='exit':
    exit()


statement = "SELECT 1 FROM Packages where TrackingNumber = %s"
mycursor.execute(statement, (val,))  

code = mycursor.fetchall()

if code:
    print ("Code Correct")
    GPIO.output( relay , 1)
    sleep(4 -time() % 1)
    GPIO.output(relay, 0)
    os.system("python3 /home/pi/Solenoidlock/lock2.py")

else:
    print ("Code Incorrect")
    os.system("python3 /home/pi/Solenoidlock/lock2.py")
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning to code and I've been looking since last night but I think I was looking to hard and couldn't find the right thing. It all works now, thanks again!